# Form text display

Tags: jquery, forms

I am making a multi-page form using http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/.  I want to include a confirmation page at the end that shows the other information (name, e-mail, etc.) as it was typed in without reloading the page.  In essence, I want to show what the user typed in on another part of the page.  I assume this would use jQuery.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it this way :

Assume this is the First Step :

```
<fieldset class="step">
            <legend>Account</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="username">User name</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
```

Your Confirmation Step should look like this

```
<fieldset class="step">
            <legend>Confirm Your Account Information</legend>
            <p>
                <span id="username_confirmation"></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span id="email_confirmation"></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span id="password_confirmation"></span>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
```

And place this JQuery code on any part of the page

```
$(function(){ $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {$("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_confirmation").html($(this).val());}); });
```

So basically what it did is to catch any keyup event on any textbox, check for an element with an ID of the related text box "plus" _confirmation.  Let's say you're typing on username textbox, on every keyup it'll look for element of "username_confirmation" and change the content of "username_confirmation" into the same value of "username"

Comment: That would be another set of fields that would have to match the original ones, correct?

Comment: Yes, but there are still plenty of workarounds. It depends on how you would like to do it. I write this up because I think this is the simplest.

Comment: I do like this method, but I would like to avoid having the user have to enter all the information twice.  I'll implement this for now though. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry,I think we're having some misunderstanding. No, they don't need to enter the information twice. What they inputted on the first step will be reflected on the confirmation step. You can do this with other text fields as well. Let's say if you have a text field with an ID of "address", so what you have to do is to create a span with an ID of "address_confirmation" on the confirmation step.